# Python Split a dict into a list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

When I get a `request.POST` in my backend I would to create a dictionary for each form.

Currently I have managed to pass the request.POST (QueryDict) to dict via `request.POST.dict()` as I have seen in some StackOverflow question, however I still have to convert this dictionary to a list of dictionaries and I don't know how.

Each form in the dict has associated the string: form-number, I would like to create a dictionary for each form.

Current dict (simplified example):

```
{'form-0-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-0-b': 'ABHD12', 'form-0-jief': 'JUGI&', 'form-1-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-1-b': 'ABHD12', 'form-1-jief': 'JUGI&', 'form-2-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-2-b': 'ABHD12', 'form-2-jief': 'JUGI&'}
```

Desired list of dicts:

```
[{'form-0-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-0-b': 'ABHD12', 'form-0-jief': 'JUGI&'}, {'form-1-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-1-b': 'ABHD12', 'form-1-jief': 'JUGI&'}, {'form-2-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-2-b': 'ABHD12', 'form-2-jief': 'JUGI&'}]
```

I am not familiar with Python so I was wondering what would be the most pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to take a minute to read through some basic tutorials before asking

Comment: @python_user I was doing some tests, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary like so.

```
dict_1= {'form-0-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-0-b': 'ABHD12', 'form-0-jief': 'JUGI&', 'form-1-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-1-b': 'ABHD12', 'form-1-jief': 'JUGI&', 'form-2-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-2-b': 'ABHD12', 'form-2-jief': 'JUGI&'}

res = {}

for key, value in dict_1.items():
    key_ = key.rsplit('-', 1)[0]
    res.setdefault(key_, {}).update({key:value})

print(list(res.values()))
```

Output

```
[{'form-0-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-0-b': 'ABHD12', 'form-0-jief': 'JUGI&'}, {'form-1-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-1-b': 'ABHD12', 'form-1-jief': 'JUGI&'}, {'form-2-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-2-b': 'ABHD12', 'form-2-jief': 'JUGI&'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def test_function():
    test = {'form-0-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-0-b': 'ABHD12', 'form-0-jief': 'JUGI&', 'form-1-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-1-b': 'ABHD12',
     'form-1-jief': 'JUGI&', 'form-2-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-2-b': 'ABHD12', 'form-2-jief': 'JUGI&'}

    form_num = 0
    new_dict = {}
    new_list = []
    for num, item in enumerate(test):

        if int(item[5]) == form_num:
            new_dict[item] = test[item]
        else:
            form_num = int(item[5])
            new_list.append(new_dict.copy())
            new_dict = {}

    new_list.append(new_dict.copy())
    print(new_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_function()
```

output

```
[{'form-0-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-0-b': 'ABHD12', 'form-0-jief': 'JUGI&'}, {'form-1-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-1-b': 'ABHD12', 'form-1-jief': 'JUGI&'}, {'form-2-a': 'MIE0158', 'form-2-b': 'ABHD12', 'form-2-jief': 'JUGI&'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can't understand why n=3

Comment: Looks like you want to separate every 3rd entry

Comment: Sorry if my example was not clear, there are N forms and each form has N elements (should be dynamic).

Comment: Edited my answer. But looks like you got a better reply anyways :)